# Array difference in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can i get the difference between  two arrays with the following structure

```
<?php

$a1 = array("0" => "red");
$a2 = array("0" => "red", "1" => "green", "2" => "blue", "3" => "yellow");
$result = arrayDiff($a1, $a2);
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';

function arrayDiff($aArray1, $aArray2) {
    $aReturn = array();

    foreach ($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) {
        if (array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) {
            if (is_array($mValue)) {
                $aRecursiveDiff = arrayDiff($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]);
                if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) {
                    $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff;
                }
            } else {
                if ($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) {
                    $aReturn[$mKey] = $aArray2[$mKey];
                }
            }
        } else {
            $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
        }
    }

    return $aReturn;
}

?>
```

Am getting an empty array as output. My preferred output is:

```
Array
(
   [0] => green
   [1] => blue
   [2] => yellow   
)
```

Comment: native php function `array_diff`?

Comment: There is a inbuild php function array_diff()

Comment: Indeed, www.php.net/array_diff

Comment: Use the inbuilt function, and make sure that the arguments are passed in the right order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array_diff function as

```
$a1 = array("0" => "red");
$a2 = array("0" => "red", "1" => "green", "2" => "blue", "3" => "yellow");
if (sizeof($a1) > sizeof($a2)) {
    $result = array_diff($a1, $a2);
} else {
    $result = array_diff($a2, $a1);
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: You can Use 'array_values' function to reset the index.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
$a1 = array("0" => "red");
$a2 = array("0" => "red", "1" => "green", "2" => "blue", "3" => "yellow");
$result = array_diff($a2, $a1);

    print_r($result);

    $result = array_values($result);
    print_r($result); 
?>
```

Comment: have you test this, it also return empty

Comment: @crack This will print precisely `Array ( [1] => green [2] => blue [3] => yellow )`

Answer (score 1):

The order is important:

```
$a1 = array("0" => "red");
$a2 = array("0" => "red", "1" => "green", "2" => "blue", "3" => "yellow");

//First Try :
$result = array_diff($a1, $a2); //Output Empty Array

//2nd Try :
$result = array_diff($a2, $a1); //Output as desired
```

You should use native PHP function http://php.net/array_diff

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1 = array("0" => "red");
$a2 = array("0" => "red", "1" => "green", "2" => "blue", "3" => "yellow");
$result = array_diff_assoc($a2, $a1);
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```

[array_diff_assoc](https://www.php.net/array_diff_assoc) — Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check

Answer (score 0):

in a simple way, you can get your desired output as:

```
$a1 = array("0" => "red");
$a2 = array("0" => "red", "1" => "green", "2" => "blue", "3" => "yellow");
foreach($a2 as $val)
{
 if(!(in_array($val,$a1)))
 {
  $result[]=$val; 
 }
}
print_r($result);
```